# FileHelpers and data type exception

Tags: filehelpers

I'm using FileHelpers library to import a tab delimited file. I have enabled the ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue. The issue I'm facing is that when  particular fields has invalid data type

```
 [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal)]
 public decimal? Price;
```

(e.g decimal? Price field has string value in it xxxxxx) in a single record, the library only checks against the first field value and throws internal exception which is logged into the ErrorManager.Errors.

I need to check the remaining fields as well on the same row and log their errors as well in the same cycle.

How can I do that?

** Please note that I have tried to writing CustomConverter but again I need to throw ConvertException so that it gets catched by ErrorManager and it just moves to next row.

The AfterReadRecord does not gets called because of the exception

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is by design from the first versions of the library, the exception is throw when found the problem or the error is logged if ErrorManager is present

The best way to solve your problem is to use a string field for Price and later do the validations you need in the AfterReadRecord method

For example

```
public class YourClass: INotifyRead
{
 [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal)]
 public string Price;

 void AfterReadRecord (...)
 // Validate inside this method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments MarcosMeli. Actually I have alot of Model classes which has alot of these properties like > 100. I want to use a reusable approach so that I don't have to code in every model class. Is there are way that I can get handle of the engine.ErroorManager in my Converter where if there is an exception I can manually log into the the Errors and continue.
My other question is that I'm reading directly into DS.If I generate these extra properties for each field in my class, would they also be populated into DT? Can I exclude them from DT?.

Comment: I have converted the field to string and created another new field of type decimal with [FieldIgnored] attribute. The validation gone good but now I'm stuck on DataTable mapping to db column. 
How can I make sure that the new field is ignored while reading from file but added into DataTable when copying into database?
Thanks

Comment: I ended up by using the old approach. i.e Read the file using engine.ReadFile(xxx) method to get the collection of records and then manually create the datatable by inserting each record into it using private fields.
Hope that's the correct way unless I did something wrong.